# How do you have more than 3 items in a for loop with os.walk?

Tags: python, os.walk

I currently have `for current_dir, dirnames, unfilenames in os.walk(input_dir):` which works fine. I'd like to be able to store an iteration variable `i`.

```
for i, current_dir, dirnames, unfilenames in os.walk(input_dir):
```

returns the following error: `ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, (current_dir, dirnames, filenames) in enumerate(os.walk(input_dir)):
```